# Windows 10 Bluetooth problems

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, bluetooth, connection

My friend cannot connect anything as the bluetooth buttons are missing on their windows. We tried going to 'Bluetooth connect', but it was surprisingly none existent. Can anyone help.

Comment: Are you sure your Device has the required hardware. If yes, please provide the make and model of your device!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you have the latest Bluetooth drivers. If you recently upgraded to Windows 10 or installed Windows 10 updates, the current driver may have been designed for an earlier version of Windows. You can update the driver in Device Manager automatically or you can manually install the latest driver by downloading it from the PC manufacturer's website.

Then, if you don't see the Bluetooth icon, but Bluetooth does appear in Device Manager, try to uninstall the Bluetooth adapter and trigger an automatic reinstall.